# How can I ask a question while not being online?

Tags: discussion, timestamps

Just came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004586/i-need-to-write-a-while-loop-which-displaying-a-random-digit) (soon to be deleted, don't be surprised to find it gone)

It says there:

[image: timestamp: 14 minutes ago]

I then turned to the profile of the OP, there it says:

[image: timestamp: 23 minutes gone]

How is that possible? (and yes, I refreshed the pages)

Comment: I don't know why but I came actoss the scenarion too. When I check **my own** profile, last seen x mins ago